# Makefile for multiple executables

Tags: makefile

Any suggestions on how to improve the `Makefile`, e.g. how to best replace the multiple uses of `example1/example2`, `ex1_src/ex2_src`, `ex1_obj/ex2_obj` with static pattern rules?

```
build := ./build
targets := $(build)/example1 $(build)/example2
src := ./src

srcfiles := $(shell find $(src) \( -name "*.cpp" -or -name "*.c" \) ! -path '*/examples/*')
objects  := $(srcfiles:%=$(build)/%.o)

ex1_src := $(shell find $(src) -name example1.cpp)
ex1_obj := $(ex1_src:%=$(build)/%.o)

ex2_src := $(shell find $(src) -name example2.cpp)
ex2_obj := $(ex2_src:%=$(build)/%.o)

all_obj := $(objects) $(ex1_obj) $(ex2_obj)
depends := $(all_obj:%.o=%.d)
incdirs := $(shell find $(src) -type d ! -path '*/examples')
includes := $(addprefix -I,$(incdirs))

CXX := g++
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++17 $(includes) -Wall -MMD -MP
LDFLAGS := -lpthread

all: $(targets)

$(build)/example1: $(objects) $(ex1_obj)
$(build)/example2: $(objects) $(ex2_obj)

$(targets):
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@

$(build)/%.cpp.o: %.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(build)

-include $(depends)
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Incorporating advice from an answer into the question violates the question-and-answer nature of this site.  You could post improved code as a new question, as an answer, or as a link to an external site - as described in [I improved my code based on the reviews. What next?](/help/someone-answers#help-post-body).  I have rolled back the edit, so the answers make sense again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually best to have the Makefile in the same directory as the build products, or at least have that as the working directory.  Then there's no need to re-write the built-in rules for compiling and linking.  Use `VPATH` to ensure the source files can be found.

> ```
> LDFLAGS := -lpthread
> ```

That should go into `LIBS` (which gets expanded later in the command line), so that it gets used as needed.  `LDFLAGS` is for flags such as `-L` which need expanding further to the left.

I'm not convinced that `example1` and `example2` are great names for your programs - surely you can think of something more descriptive and memorable for your users?

> ```
> ex1_src := $(shell find $(src) -name example1.cpp)
> ```

Do you really need to invoke a `find` there?  I would expect there to be few enough matches that you could simply list them, and update the list when you add a new one.  I'd do the same for `srcfiles` too - or create a library, so that the resultant programs only include the objects they need.

I think generally there's too much use of shells here, despite them all being in `:=` assignments.  You want makefile parsing to be *fast*, so you can see all your unit test results as quickly as possible.

So I'd write

```
example1: example1.o object_a.o object_b.o object_c.o
example1: LINK.o = $(LINK.cc)
```

The target-specific `LINK.o` is necessary so that the C++ linker is used.  It's cleaner and more portable than adding the C++ runtime library to `LIBS`.

You're missing some very important `CXXFLAGS`:

```
CXXFLAGS += -Wall -Wextra
```

I'd likely add a few more:

```
CXXFLAGS += -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds -Weffc++
CXXFLAGS += -Werror
```

Good use of `.PHONY` - that's often overlooked.

You should also have `.DELETE_ON_ERROR:` so that interrupted builds don't cause problems.

Comment: Thanks! +1 Only one concern, I dont like to have all objects and deps in the top level build folder. Any good advice for that?

Comment: I don't see why not - it's the way Make is designed to work.  It's nice to have all the products in one place - then you can clean just by deleting the build directory.  If you want to work against Make, then that's your choice of course.  But I find it easier to let the built-in rules carry the load, and have a makefile that follows convention so that anyone else can follow it.